# How i can change the line number color in monaco-editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

I want to change line number color in **monaco-editor**. I don't know how. Can anyone help me? **My code for defining a theme.**

```js
monaco.editor.defineTheme('my-dark', {
    base: 'vs-dark',
    inherit: true,
    rules: [
        { token: 'global', foreground: '84d6f7', fontStyle: "bold" },
        { token: 'keyword', foreground: 'f86d7c', fontStyle: "bold" },
        { token: 'comment', foreground: '666666' },
        { token: 'number', foreground: 'fcc600' },
        { token: 'string', foreground: 'ffc43a' },
    ],
    colors: {
        "editor.background": '#191919'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the `editorLineNumber.foreground` color key.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `colors` dictionary.

So basically there are two variables that I found:

```js
...
colors: {
    // set a default line number color here
    editorLineNumber.foreground: "#000000",
    // set an active line number color here
    editorLineNumber.activeForeground: "#D2360F" 
}
...
```